# Querying XML using JQuery.find() provides unexpected results if jQuery object is created from an XML Document

Tags: jquery, xml, find, xforms

I noticed different results when querying XML with jQuery, depending on how the jQuery object is instantiated, ie. from an **XML Document** or from an **XML string**. The former gives unexpected results and I'm guessing I'm missing something here.

```
xmlStr = '<data>'+
               '<node1 />'+
               '<node2 template="">'+
                      '<node2a>def</node2a>'+
               '</node2>'+
               '<node2>'+
                      '<node2a>val2a</node2a>'+
               '</node2>'+
               '<node2 />'+
               '<node3>a value</node3>'+
         '</data>';

dataXMLDoc = $.parseXML(xmlStr);
$dataXDoc = $(dataXMLDoc);
$data = $(xmlStr);

//queries using $dataXDoc (created from XML Document)
console.log('1a:length: '+$dataXDoc.find('node2a:not([template], [template] *)').length); //finds 1
console.log('2a:length: '+$dataXDoc.find('*:not([template], [template] *)').find('node2a').length); //finds *2*
console.log('3a:length: '+$dataXDoc.find('*').not('[template], [template] *').find('node2a').length); //finds *2*
console.log('4a:length: '+$dataXDoc.find('*:not([template], [template] *)').find('node2a').length); //finds *2*

//queries using $data (created from XML String)
console.log('1b:length: '  +  $data.find('node2a:not([template], [template] *)').length);  //finds 1
console.log('2b:length: '  +  $data.find('*:not([template], [template] *)').find('node2a').length); //finds 1
console.log('3b:length: '  +  $data.find('*').not('[template], [template] *').find('node2a').length); //finds 1
console.log('4b:length: '  +  $data.find('*:not([template], [template] *)').find('node2a').length); //finds 1
```

I realize using subsequent find()s makes no sense in this particular example and that 1a and 1b are the best choice in this context. However, shouldn't 2a, 3a and 4a give the same results? Why not?

Basically, I'm trying to exclude nodes that have a template attribute and nodes that are descendants of a node with a template attribute, BEFORE I try to find the node I want.

EDIT 1:
Thanks to @Steven, this provides the same results for both JQuery Objects (excluding the XMLDocument itself):

```
console.log('2a:length: '+$dataXDoc.find('* *:not([template], [template] *)').find('node2a').length); //finds *1*
console.log('3a:length: '+$dataXDoc.find('* *').not('[template], [template] *').find('node2a').length); //finds *1*
console.log('4a:length: '+$dataXDoc.find('* *:not([template], [template] *)').find('node2a').length); //finds *1*
```

EDIT 2:
When testing with a more complex XML Document I noticed there is still a problem. The trick with subsequent find()s is that you have to apply the :not filter again on the second set (which makes the first :not filter kind of obsolete). Only then do you get the correct results. It helps to visualize the different stages by logging the results as @Steve mentioned  below.

EDIT 3:
This would be a solution if I want a standard way of accessing the subset before the final find(). First select the leaf nodes excluding templates and their children using a filter. Then do a search on this $subset to $subset like the example below.

```
$subset = $dataXDoc.find('*:not([template], [template] *)').filter(function(){return $(this).children().length == 0});
$node = $subset.filter('node2a');
```

EDIT 4:
corrected EDIT 3

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the output at each step for the find command chains:

```
console.log($dataXDoc);
console.log($dataXDoc.find('*:not([template], [template] *)'));
console.log($dataXDoc.find('*:not([template], [template] *)').find('node2a'));
```

versus

```
console.log($data);
console.log($data.find('*:not([template], [template] *)'));
console.log($data.find('*:not([template], [template] *)').find('node2a'));
```

You'll see that the xmlDocument itself matches the `*` selector, which then gives you your second match, but in the xml string's case jQuery parses it as xml, but does not create an xml document.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only weird thing is that I would expect the first block to return two nodes, both with content "val2a". Instead I see one node with "def" and one node with "val2a". In any case using: `$dataXDoc.find('* *:not([template], [template] *)').find('node2a')` gets the correct result, so I'll mark it as SOLVED!

Comment: On second thought, that was only part of the problem... I have to change my approach. See edit2 above.

Comment: Oh, you want to find all node2a tags? I think in answering last time I forget what the purpose was.  maybe something like this would work for you? `$dataXDoc.find('node1,node2,node3').not('[template]').find('node2a')`

Comment: Yes, all node2a tags that do not have a template attribute and are not a child of a node with a template attribute. The problem is that I won't know the names of the nodes so `.find('node1, node2, node3')` won't work and `.find('*')` still selects ancestors of template nodes (and a subsequent find() therefore includes the unwanted template/template-child nodes again ). Quite tricky, but I'll just have to query differently.

Comment: Do you know the name of the leaf nodes you are selecting? In your example the node2a? Like this? `$dataXDoc.find('* > *:not([template], [template] *)').find('node2a')`

Comment: I appreciate the help Steve! Yes, I do, but the code did not do what I wanted. However, I figured out that an approach whereby I only select leaf nodes could be a solution (other than cloning and removing template nodes). The following selects the correct subset of leaf nodes excluding children of template nodes.  `$dataXDoc.find('*:not([template], [template] *)').filter(function(){return $(this).children().length == 0})`. Unfortunately, find() doesn't work on this subset because it only searches descendants. I guess the best way to do would be to use a filter that checks .prop('nodeName').